# Pandas iterrows jump to a new index, row to continue iteration

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

Greatings,

I know iterrows may not be the best way to perform this so I am open to other ideas as well, but I really would like to know how to do the following:

Say I have loop inside a loop (yikes!) going through the same data frame and when I end the second loop I want the index, row on the first loop to start off where the second loop finished (ie index = index2 in code below).  Here is my example code:

```py
    from pandas import *

    df = DataFrame(
        {'to': ['spot1', 'spot2', 'spot3', 'spot4', 'spot1', 'spot3', 'spot5'],
         'from': ['Denver','Denver','Denver','Denver','Cleveland','Cleveland','Timbuktu']})`

    for index, row in df.iterrows():     #iterate to find functions for measurement    
        
        value1 = row['from'] 
                
        for index2, row2 in islice(df.iterrows(), index+1, None):  #use islice to start on next row

            value2 = row2['from']

            if value1 != value2:            
                print('leaving from new destination)
                
                index = index2  #start outside loop at location where inside loop finished (ie value1 = Cleveland on second outside iteration)             
                
                break   #stop loop to prevent needless looping

            elif value1 == value2:
        
                print('still leaving from same destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you only need a single for, for example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
     'to': ['spot1', 'spot2', 'spot3', 'spot4', 'spot1', 'spot3', 'spot5'],
     'from':['Denver','Denver','Denver','Denver','Cleveland','Cleveland','Timbuktu']
  }
)
current_idx = df.iloc[0].name  # get first index
current_from = df.loc[current_idx, "from"]

for idx, row in df.iloc[1:].iterrows():  # Iter from the second row
  if current_from == row["from"]:
    print('still leaving from same destination')
  else:
     print('leaving from new destination')
     current_idx = idx
     current_from = row["from"]
```

Honestly, you don't need keep the index hahah